# Boost algorithm with lambda fails to compile

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, lambda

The following example code:

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE // does not help

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <future>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

struct DW {
    std::promise<bool> success_;
};

template <class T>
class Pool
{
public:
    Pool() : container_{}
    {};
public:
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin() { return container_.begin(); }
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator end()   { return container_.end(); }
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator begin() const { return container_.begin(); }
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator end()   const { return container_.end(); }
private:
    std::vector<T>     container_;     ///< holder of elements
};

#define LAMBDA [] (DW& w) { return w.success_.get_future().get(); }

int main()
{
    Pool<DW> vec;

    auto s = std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), LAMBDA);
    auto b = boost::count_if(vec, LAMBDA);

    return (s == b) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

fails to compile with GCC 4.8.5, 6.2 or 8 :

```
g++ -g -pthread -std=gnu++0x -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wformat=2 -o "ranger" "ranger.cpp" (in directory: /tmp)
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/iterator/iterator_categories.hpp:15:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/iterator/iterator_concepts.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/range/concepts.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm.hpp:29,
                 from ranger.cpp:6:
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::mpl::eval_if_c<false, boost::range_const_iterator<Pool<DW>, void>, boost::range_mutable_iterator<Pool<DW>, void> >’:
/usr/local/include/boost/range/iterator.hpp:69:17:   required from ‘struct boost::range_iterator<Pool<DW>, void>’
/usr/local/include/boost/range/difference_type.hpp:26:12:   required from ‘struct boost::range_difference<Pool<DW> >’
/usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm/count_if.hpp:32:1:   required by substitution of ‘template<class SinglePassRange, class UnaryPredicate> typename boost::range_difference<T>::type boost::range::count_if(SinglePassRange&, UnaryPredicate) [with SinglePassRange = Pool<DW>; UnaryPredicate = main()::__lambda5]’
ranger.cpp:34:41:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:60:31: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘boost::mpl::eval_if_c<false, boost::range_const_iterator<Pool<DW>, void>, boost::range_mutable_iterator<Pool<DW>, void> >::f_ {aka struct boost::range_mutable_iterator<Pool<DW>, void>}’
     typedef typename f_::type type;
                               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::mpl::eval_if_c<true, boost::range_const_iterator<Pool<DW>, void>, boost::range_mutable_iterator<const Pool<DW>, void> >’:
/usr/local/include/boost/range/iterator.hpp:69:17:   required from ‘struct boost::range_iterator<const Pool<DW>, void>’
/usr/local/include/boost/range/difference_type.hpp:26:12:   required from ‘struct boost::range_difference<const Pool<DW> >’
/usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm/count_if.hpp:41:1:   required by substitution of ‘template<class SinglePassRange, class UnaryPredicate> typename boost::range_difference<const SinglePassRange>::type boost::range::count_if(const SinglePassRange&, UnaryPredicate) [with SinglePassRange = Pool<DW>; UnaryPredicate = main()::__lambda5]’
ranger.cpp:34:41:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:60:31: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘boost::mpl::eval_if_c<true, boost::range_const_iterator<Pool<DW>, void>, boost::range_mutable_iterator<const Pool<DW>, void> >::f_ {aka struct boost::range_const_iterator<Pool<DW>, void>}’
ranger.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ranger.cpp:34:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘count_if(Pool<DW>&, main()::__lambda5)’
     auto b = boost::count_if(vec, LAMBDA);
                                         ^
ranger.cpp:34:41: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm.hpp:40:0,
                 from ranger.cpp:6:
/usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm/count_if.hpp:41:1: note: template<class SinglePassRange, class UnaryPredicate> typename boost::range_difference<const SinglePassRange>::type boost::range::count_if(const SinglePassRange&, UnaryPredicate)
 count_if(const SinglePassRange& rng, UnaryPredicate pred)
 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm/count_if.hpp:41:1: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
/usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm/count_if.hpp:32:1: note: template<class SinglePassRange, class UnaryPredicate> typename boost::range_difference<T>::type boost::range::count_if(SinglePassRange&, UnaryPredicate)
 count_if(SinglePassRange& rng, UnaryPredicate pred)
 ^
/usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm/count_if.hpp:32:1: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
Compilation failed.
```

and also with clang 5.0.0 (trunk 302784)

```
$ clang++ -g -pthread -std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wformat=2  -o "ranger" "ranger.cpp" (in directory: /tmp)
In file included from ranger.cpp:6:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm.hpp:29:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/range/concepts.hpp:20:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/iterator/iterator_concepts.hpp:10:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/iterator/iterator_categories.hpp:15:
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:60:26: error: no type named 'type' in 'boost::range_mutable_iterator<Pool<DW>, void>'
    typedef typename f_::type type;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/range/iterator.hpp:65:31: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::mpl::eval_if_c<false, boost::range_const_iterator<Pool<DW>, void>, boost::range_mutable_iterator<Pool<DW>, void> >' requested here
        typedef typename mpl::eval_if_c<
                              ^
/usr/local/include/boost/range/difference_type.hpp:28:40: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::range_iterator<Pool<DW>, void>' requested here
                BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME range_iterator<
                                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm/count_if.hpp:31:38: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::range_difference<Pool<DW> >' requested here
inline BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::range_difference<SinglePassRange>::type
                                     ^
ranger.cpp:34:14: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'count_if' [with SinglePassRange = Pool<DW>, UnaryPredicate = (lambda at ranger.cpp:34:35)]
    auto b = boost::count_if(vec, LAMBDA);
             ^
In file included from ranger.cpp:6:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm.hpp:29:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/range/concepts.hpp:20:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/iterator/iterator_concepts.hpp:10:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/iterator/iterator_categories.hpp:15:
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:60:26: error: no type named 'type' in 'boost::range_const_iterator<Pool<DW>, void>'
    typedef typename f_::type type;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/range/iterator.hpp:65:31: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::mpl::eval_if_c<true, boost::range_const_iterator<Pool<DW>, void>, boost::range_mutable_iterator<const Pool<DW>, void> >' requested here
        typedef typename mpl::eval_if_c<
                              ^
/usr/local/include/boost/range/difference_type.hpp:28:40: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::range_iterator<const Pool<DW>, void>' requested here
                BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME range_iterator<
                                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm/count_if.hpp:40:38: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::range_difference<const Pool<DW> >' requested here
inline BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::range_difference<const SinglePassRange>::type
                                     ^
ranger.cpp:34:14: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'count_if' [with SinglePassRange = Pool<DW>, UnaryPredicate = (lambda at ranger.cpp:34:35)]
    auto b = boost::count_if(vec, LAMBDA);
             ^
ranger.cpp:34:14: error: no matching function for call to 'count_if'
    auto b = boost::count_if(vec, LAMBDA);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm/count_if.hpp:32:1: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with SinglePassRange = Pool<DW>, UnaryPredicate = (lambda at ranger.cpp:34:35)]
count_if(SinglePassRange& rng, UnaryPredicate pred)
^
/usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm/count_if.hpp:41:1: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with SinglePassRange = Pool<DW>, UnaryPredicate = (lambda at ranger.cpp:34:35)]
count_if(const SinglePassRange& rng, UnaryPredicate pred)
^
3 errors generated.
Compilation failed.
```

Isn't `boost::algo(range)` supposed to be a drop-in replacement for `std::algo(range.begin(), range.end())` ?

Comment: So, does it work with plain old `vector<DW>`?  How about `vector<int>` with a simple lambda `[](int x){return x%2;}`?  `Pool<int>`?  A lambda not generated by macro?  I'm wondering what of your relatively complex setup is required.

Comment: Looks like you missing certain typedef's in `Pool` like `difference_type`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was wondering about that; but if boost doesn't suck, it should be able to deduce these things from `decltype( std::declval<Pool>().begin() )` and `iterator_traits` on that no?  I'm not familiar with this particular boost API, but I try to assume the best of APIs.

Comment: @Yakk I was hoping that it would but it doesn't look like it does.  Adding `std::vector<DW> foo;` to main and then doing `auto b = boost::count_if(foo, LAMBDA);` works just fine so I think they want the traits in the container and not the iterator.

Comment: Yes, it does work with plain old `vector<DW>`. The lambda is a macro to show that it's the same (I didn't want to copy-paste it from the std algorithm to the boost one).

Comment: @Bulletmagnet I was just stating that a `auto lambda = [] (DW& w) { return w.success_.get_future().get(); };` then using it would get rid of preprocessor usage, yet not require copy/paste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define `iterator` and `const_iterator` in your `Pool` class. The Boost Algorithm library was written before C++11 and it does not use `decltype` to find out the iterator type. Unfortunately, it is still not updated to use it if available, so you have to define the iterator type. It is a good practice anyway.

```
template <class T>
class Pool
{
public:
    Pool() : container_{}
    {};
public:
    using iterator = typename std::vector<T>::iterator;
    using const_iterator = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator;

    iterator begin() { return container_.begin(); }
    iterator end()   { return container_.end(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return container_.begin(); }
    const_iterator end()   const { return container_.end(); }
private:
    std::vector<T>     container_;     ///< holder of elements
};
```

Comment: You can go further and define the myriad of typedefs that C++ standard containers tend to have: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list -- forward list has a pretty minimal set.  Most of them seem identical to what you can get from `std::iterator_traits<iterator>`.

Comment: Bingo! Both `iterator` and `const_iterator` are needed.